# Open window with filter in Cuba Platform controller

Tags: cuba-platform

I have some links on my dashboard, which link to myCustomers or allCostomerThatRegisteredYesterday. I have used the application-folder. For the usability is a dashboard with quicklinks even better.

How can I call openWindow("screen-id",WindowType,filterMap?) with a filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. You can use a Query Filter (see [https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.1/manual.html#datasource_query_filter](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.1/datasource_query_filter)). So your datasource definition will look like this:

```xml
    <collectionDatasource id="booksDs"
                          class="com.company.opentest.entity.Book"
                          view="_local">
        <query>
            <![CDATA[select e from opentest$Book e]]>
            <filter>
                <and>
                    <c>e.author.id = :param$bookAuthor</c>
                </and>
            </filter>
        </query>
    </collectionDatasource>
```

In this case, if you pass a `bookAuthor` param in the params argument of the `openWindow` method, this query filter will be applied.

```java
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("bookAuthor", author);
    openWindow("opentest$Book.browse", WindowManager.OpenType.NEW_TAB, params);
```

2. If you want to use a [Generic filter](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.1/gui_Filter.html) component and set the predefined filter entity to it, then it is a bit more complex. You'll have to analyze the parameters map that is passed to the screen `init()` method, and if there is a special parameter there, you'll have find the required filter entity (`sec$Filter`) by the JPQL query. Then set this entity to the Filter component (`Filter#setFilterEntity(...)`), specify filter parameters (`Filter#setParamValue(...)`) and apply the filter (`Filter#apply()`).

Getting filter parameter name (author84104) is described at the `setParamValue()` method javadoc and at the filter component documentation.

```java
public class BookBrowse extends AbstractLookup {

    @Inject
    private Filter filter;

    @Inject
    private DataManager dataManager;

    private Author bookAuthorParam;

    @Override
    public void init(Map<String, Object> params) {
        super.init(params);
        bookAuthorParam = (Author) params.get("bookAuthor");
    }

    @Override
    public void ready() {
        super.ready();
        if (bookAuthorParam != null) {
            setAuthorFilter(bookAuthorParam);
        }
    }

    private void setAuthorFilter(Author bookAuthor) {
        FilterEntity filterEntity = findFilterEntity();
        if (filterEntity != null) {
            filter.setFilterEntity(filterEntity);
            filter.setParamValue("author84104", bookAuthor);
            filter.apply(false);
        }
    }

    private FilterEntity findFilterEntity() {
        LoadContext<FilterEntity> ctx = new LoadContext<>(FilterEntity.class)
                .setView("app");
        ctx.setQueryString("select f from sec$Filter f where f.componentId = :componentId and f.name = :name")
                .setParameter("componentId", "[opentest$Book.browse].filter")
                .setParameter("name", "By author");
        return dataManager.load(ctx);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first case: I want to get all books where the author is null. How could I do?

Comment: You can pass some boolean parameter like `noAuthor = true` when you open the books browser. Then inside the `init()` method of books controller analyze the params map. If it contains the `noAuthor` param, then set a new query to the datasource and refresh it
`booksDs.setQuery("select b from booktest$Book b where b.author is null");`
`booksDs.refresh();`

Comment: It will work only if is no condition defined in access groups. I get an error like this: `Problem compiling [select c from lib$Book b where (b.state = new) and (b.userExt.id = :session$userId)]. 
The basic mapping 'b.state' cannot be used in conjunction with the = operator...` Where _new_ was set as parameter _:newState_. I guess it has been compiled or replaced before the access group filter was added.